# XAMPP Apache not working on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, xampp, htdocs

I have been searching for hours now and I cant find a solution. I have tried much to many things to even start listing the things. So please any assistance would be appreciated.

I have changed the `htdocs` folder location in `httpd.conf` because I have all my files sync to cloud storage. This works perfectly on my windows machine but on linux not so much. Every thing runs perfectly but when I try to access my `htdocs` folder (new location) I get a message:

```
Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
localhost
Apache/2.4.48 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.10 mod_perl/2.0.11 Perl/v5.32.1
```

But When I change the location back to the normal location it works perfectly.

I have already gave full access to the folder.

Comment: "I have already gave full access to the folder." — What exactly does this mean?

Comment: The new htdocs folder has complete read and write access

Comment: What about the parent folder?

Comment: I just did it and fixed the problem thank you

Answer (score 0):

Think of a directory structure as a series of security doors:

```
/var
/www
/htdocs
```

If you give someone a key to `htdocs` (i.e. set the permissions to give a user access) then they can open that door… but only if they can get to it.

If you don't also give them keys to `www` and `var` then they can't get into `htdocs`.